# Proof that $(a+b)^{1/n} \leq a^{1/n} + b^{1/n}$

Tags: calculus, inequality, proof-verification

I don't really know how to start here.

I tried to proof it by induction but don't know how to continue the inductive step. I got $ (a+b)^{1/(p+1)} \leq a^{1/(p+1)} + b^{1/(p+1)} $

I also tried to figure out a way by ignoring the $^{1/n}$ and to write $(a+b)^c \leq a^c + b^c$ instead, but couldn't figure out how to continue without using proof by induction because $c$ would be a  rational number.

So does anyone have an idea on how to solve this? Which method to use?

Comment: Binomial theorem?

Comment: should I still use proof by induction?

Comment: Use Jensen's inequality

Answer (score 2):

I assume $a,b\geq 0$. The binomial formula implies: $(a^{1/n}+b^{1/n})^n=(a^{1/n})^n+(b^{1/n})^n+..=a+b+...\geq a+b=((a+b)^{1/n})^n$

Comment: how does $a+b+...$ continue?

Comment: Use this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Theorem_statement

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I understand it but got one question. What happens if n = {1,2,3,4,...}?

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned before, the Binomial Theorem works well here.
The binomial theorem says that you can expand $(a+b)^n$ in the following way:
$$(a+b)^n = \sum_{i = 0}^n\binom{n}{i}a^ib^{n-i}$$
The easiest way to apply this is to prove the inequality for $a+b\leq(a^{1/n}+b^{1/n})^n$.
To do this, we apply Binomial Theorem to the right hand side:
$$(a^{1/n}+b^{1/n})^n = \sum_{i = 0}^n \binom{n}{i}(a^{1/n})^i{(b^{1/n})}^{n-i}$$
Importantly, this sum on the right hand side is:
$$\sum_{i = 0}^n \binom{n}{i}(a^{1/n})^i{(b^{1/n})}^{n-i} = b+\sum_{i = 1}^{n-1} \binom{n}{i}(a^{1/n})^i{(b^{1/n})}^{n-i}+a = a+b+c$$
Where $c$ is the rest of the sum.
Assuming that $a,b\geq 0$, we'll get that $c\geq 0$ too, so $a+b+c\geq a+b$.
But we have from before that $a+b+c = (a^{1/n}+b^{1/n})^n$, so this is:
$$(a^{1/n}+b^{1/n})^n\geq a+b\implies a^{1/n}+b^{1/n}\geq (a+b)^{1/n}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I understand it but got one question. What happens if n = {1,2,3,4,...}?

Answer (score 0):

Let $0<c<1$. Define
$$ f(x)=(a+x)^{c}-a^{c}-x^{c}, x>0. $$
Then
$$ f'(x)=c(\frac{1}{(a+x)^{1-c}}-\frac{1}{x^{1-c}})<0, x>0$$
and hence $f(x)$ is decreasing for $x\ge0$. Thus $f(x)\le f(0)=0$ for any $x\ge0$ and hence for $b\ge0$, $f(b)\le 0$, or
$$ (a+b)^{c}\le a^{c}+b^{c}. $$

Answer (score 0):

Here we prove a more general result.

For any $0<p<1$ and $a\geqslant 0,b\geqslant 0$, there is
$$
(a+b)^p\leqslant a^p+b^p\tag1
$$
If $a=b=0$, $(1)$ clearly holds. Assume $a\neq 0$ and let $x=\frac{a}{a+b}$. Then $(1)$ becomes 
$$
1\leqslant x^p+(1-x)^p\tag2
$$
Clearly $0\leqslant x\leqslant 1$. Let $f(x)=x^p+(1-x)^p$. Then
$$
f'(x)=px^{p-1}-p(1-x)^{p-1}
$$
Since $f'(1/2)=0$ and 
\begin{cases}
f'(x)>0, \quad 0<x<1/2\\
f'(x)<0, \quad 1/2<x<1
\end{cases}
$f(1/2)$ is the only maximum point in $[0,1]$.  Since $f(0)=f(1)=1$, $f(x)\geqslant 1$ on $[0,1]$. And so $(1)$ is true.